# React- Button Onclick NOT rendering a file from file-system - On any click on the link Its alwasys rendering the last file from the files-object

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am relatively new to React and certainly in this project I am missing something basic.

I have uploaded a small sample project with this functionality in [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/52l1j1l9nx) . Although you will see error in codesandbox (because as of now dont think it supports node and mongo backend). Pushed the code there only to show whole project.

Here’s the project flow.

**Its a full-stack project, and I have few files uploaded to the project’s file-system using node and mongodb in the /uploads directory. However my current issue is ONLY in the React front-end which is about rendering the uploaded files on click of a button. From the React front-end I am rendering those files by clicking on a button and then opening a Material-UI modal. So each time a user click on the "Download file" a Modal opens and inside that Modal I click on the "View File" button the relevant file should be rendered in a new tab.
But each time I am clicking on the view file, an uploaded file is indeed been rendered but always its the last file in the ‘images’ object.**

Here’s my `../src/Components/FileUpload.js` which has Material-UI modal implemented. The handleClose function takes a single parameter `fileLink` which is the link of the file that I am fetching from the `images` object.

```
class FileUpload extends Component {
  state = {
    documents: [],
    open: false
  };

  handleClickOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleClose = fileLink => {
    this.setState({
      open: false
    });
    window.open(`${fileLink}`, "_blank");
  };

  deleteDocument = id => {
    axios.delete("/api/document/" + id).then(() => {
      this.setState({
        documents: this.state.documents.filter(document => document._id !== id)
      });
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("/api/document").then(res => {
      this.setState({ documents: res.data });
    });
  }

  importAll = result => {
    let images = {};
    result.keys().map((item, index) => {
      return (images[item.replace("./", "")] = result(item));
    });
    return images;
  };

  render() {
    const webpackContext = require.context(
      "../../uploads",
      false,
      /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|pdf|doc|odt)$/
    );

    const images = this.importAll(webpackContext);
    console.log(images);

    return (
      <div className="bg-success">
        <Col xs="8">
          <Card>
            <CardHeader className="p-2 mb-2 bg-primary text-white" />
            <CardBody>
              <CardText>
                <table className="table table-stripe">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Document Id</th>
                      <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    {this.state.documents.map(document => (
                      <tr>
                        <td>{document.document_id}</td>
                        <td>{document.description}</td>
                        <td>
                          <Button onClick={this.handleClickOpen}>
                            Download file
                          </Button>
                          <Dialog
                            open={this.state.open}
                            onClose={this.handleClose}
                            aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
                          >
                            <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">
                              Required Information
                            </DialogTitle>
                            <DialogContent>
                              <DialogContentText>
                                Update these info to download the file
                              </DialogContentText>
                              <TextField
                                autoFocus
                                margin="dense"
                                id="name"
                                label="Email Address"
                                type="email"
                                fullWidth
                              />
                            </DialogContent>
                            <DialogActions>
                              <Button
                                onClick={this.handleClose}
                                color="primary"
                              >
                                Cancel
                              </Button>
                              <Button
                                onClick={this.handleClose.bind(
                                  this,
                                  images[`${document.path}`]
                                )}
                                color="primary"
                              >
                                Download file
                              </Button>
                            </DialogActions>
                          </Dialog>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <Link
                            to={`/api/document/edit/${document._id}`}
                            class="btn btn-success"
                          >
                            Edit Description
                          </Link>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <button
                            onClick={this.deleteDocument.bind(
                              this,
                              document._id
                            )}
                            className="btn btn-danger"
                          >
                            Delete
                          </button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    ))}
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </CardText>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </Col>
```

```

So, on click of the Button I am doing a

`onClick={this.handleClose.bind}` passing to the `handleClose` funtion the parameter of the filepath link ( i.e. the link with which I should be able to render that file )

And I am picking up the file link from an object that I have created in this compoenent itself with Webpack’s require.context and saving in the variable named **images** with

`const images = this.importAll(webpackContext);`

But each time I am clicking on the view file, an uploaded file is indeed been rendered but always its the last file in the ‘images’ object.

The `handleClose` function is not picking up the other files in the images object.

Comment: It's broken pal `require.context is not a function`

Comment: codesandbox will not run, I pushed the code there just to show my whole project - to see the full project you have to download to your machine and then do  `sudo service mongod start` and then the following regular commands

- `npm install`
- `npm run dev`

Comment: How about using an arrow function instead of using bind here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question (in case it helps anybody else) -

The mistake I was making is this -

When passing data from my `FileUpload.js` `.map` function to the `handleClose` funtion passing the fileLink to render, I was not implementing any way to hook into that particluar file referred by the link.
Corrected it by A) From FileUpload.js when clicking on the Button to Download/View file, now I am rendering a completely new component ( `RenderFile.js`) which will take care of opening the Material-UI modal and rendering the correct link for viewing the file.

This is my updated FileUpload.js file

```
class FileUpload extends Component {
  state = {
    documents: [],
    clicked: false,
    textBeforeDownload: "View/Download"
  };


  launchRenderFileComp = () => {
    this.setState({
      clicked: true,
      textBeforeDownload: ""
    });
  };

  deleteDocument = id => {
    axios.delete("/api/document/" + id).then(() => {
      this.setState({
        documents: this.state.documents.filter(document => document._id !== id)
      });
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("/api/document").then(res => {
      this.setState({ documents: res.data });
    });
  }

  importAll = result => {
    let images = {};
    result.keys().map((item, index) => {
      return (images[item.replace("./", "")] = result(item));
    });
    return images;
  };

  render() {
    const { documents } = this.state;

    const webpackContext = require.context(
      "../../uploads",
      false,
      /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|pdf|doc|odt)$/
    );

    const images = this.importAll(webpackContext);
    return (
      <div className="bg-success">
        <Col xs="8">
          <Card>
            <CardHeader className="p-2 mb-2 bg-primary text-white" />
            <CardBody>
              <CardText>
                <table className="table table-stripe">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Document Id</th>
                      <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    {documents.map(document => (
                      <tr>
                        <td>{document.document_id}</td>
                        <td>{document.description}</td>
                        <td>
                          <Button onClick={this.launchRenderFileComp}>
                            {this.state.clicked ? (
                              <RenderFile linkForRender={document.path} />
                            ) : null}
                            {this.state.textBeforeDownload}
                          </Button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <Link
                            to={`/api/document/edit/${document._id}`}
                            class="btn btn-success"
                          >
                            Edit Description
                          </Link>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <button
                            onClick={this.deleteDocument.bind(
                              this,
                              document._id
                            )}
                            className="btn btn-danger"
                          >
                            Delete
                          </button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    ))}
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </CardText>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </Col>
```

And this is the new RenderFile.js compoenent that will take care of both opening the modal and rendering the file.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@material-ui/core/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";

class RenderFile extends Component {
  state = {
    open: false
  };

  handleToggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
    });
  };

  handleClickOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleClose = file => {
    // file = this.file;
    this.setState({
      open: false
    });
    window.open(`${file}`, "_blank");
  };

  handleCancel = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  importAll = result => {
    let images = {};
    result.keys().map((item, index) => {
      return (images[item.replace("./", "")] = result(item));
    });
    return images;
  };

  render() {
    const webpackContext = require.context(
      "../../uploads",
      false,
      /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|pdf|doc|odt)$/
    );

    const images = this.importAll(webpackContext);
    const { linkForRender } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.handleClickOpen}>Click to View File</Button>
        <Dialog
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.handleToggle}
          aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
        >
          <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Required Information</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>
              Update these info to download the file
            </DialogContentText>
            <TextField
              autoFocus
              margin="dense"
              id="name"
              label="Email Address"
              type="email"
              fullWidth
            />
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={this.handleCancel} color="primary">
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button
              onClick={this.handleClose.bind(this, images[`${linkForRender}`])}
              color="primary"
            >
              View or Download File
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```